# Trouble connecting phone to arduino using droidScript

Tags: arduino-uno, android-7.1-nougat, usb-otg, sony-xperia, droidscript

I am trying to connect my sony xperia sp running on android 7.1 ( Lineage OS ) to my arduino uno using an OTG cable and the droidScript app. It worked perfectly the first time, it asked permission to open droidScript : I clicked on "OK" and checked "Use by default for this USB device".

But now I can't get it to work. When I reconnect my phone to the Uno nothing happen on my phone, droidScrip does not seem to recognize the device either and now when I try to connect my phone to my computer it does not work either ( but it's charging ).

I have tested all my cables and connected the arduino the same way using a different phone several times and it worked ( but didn't allow "Use by default for this USB device" as I suspect it comes from here ). Manually enable MTP through dev options does not work.

How can I remove that "Use by default for this USB device" option, and get the asking permission box back when I connect to my Uno ?

Answer (score 0):

Try unistalling DroidScript and any other apps that might have talked to that USB device and then re-install DroidScript but don't start it up.

Plugin the OTG cable to the device (make sure you get it the right way round so that the OTG cable goes into the phone end) and then you should see the popup box for permissions.